# Can Tizen Watch app receive push without a smart phone?

Tags: push-notification, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am wondering if a wi-fi enabled Tizen smartwatch can receive push notifications directly from server without a smart phone in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Which watch ? I think Gear2 has only SAP support for connectivity, BT support is not open to applications developers , while S1 and S2 are supporting wifi but I havent checked on later ones ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a Tizen push service.
But be aware that this feature is marked as optional and my not be available on all devices.

See Tizen Tutorials: [Push: Receiving Push Notifications from a Push Server](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/communication/push)